# Curly braces in shell script while passing argument

Tags: shell

Hi I am new to shell script. I want to pass an argument to a shell script. I know how to do the same.I have written a simple shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
parameter=$1
whatispased=${parameter:-"nothing"}
echo $whatispassed
```

If something is passed as the first argument, it is printed else "nothing" is printed. I have seen some people writing.

```
parameter=${1,,}
```

i tried replacing the first line with the one above, but i am getting a bad substitution error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Save yourself troubles and use quotes a lot to survive a lot of characters. Less than perfect but better than no defense at all: whatispased="${1:-"nothing"}";
echo "$whatispassed";

Comment: i just wanted to confirm what the second format is doing

Comment: actually in the new version of bash, it converts the argument to lowercase. just went through the features of bash 4.0. thanks for the support though

Answer (score 2):

First you can reduce this to:

```
#!/bin/bash
whatispassed=${1:-"nothing"}
echo $whatispassed
```

or even:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${1:-"nothing"}
```

For `${parameter,,pattern}` look into [`Shell Parameter Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

For more on bash or shell scripting, see [info:bash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6798269/1741542.

Comment: actually in the new version of bash, it converts the argument to lowercase. just went through the features of bash 4.0, Got it, thanks for the support though.

Comment: is there any book which helps to understand the above kind of bash scripting I am a bit new to this